# Place custom markers for leaflet.draw marker property

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, markers, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet.draw plugin to allow the user to place markers on the map but not sure how to provide  configure in drawControl  to take custom icon ,custom width and custom  height tried doing it as shown below

```
var  drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw : {
                position : 'topleft',
                polygon : {
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
                },
                marker:{
                    iconUrl: 'http://joshuafrazier.info/images/firefox.svg'
                },
                polyline : false,
                rectangle : {
                    shapeOptions: {
                        color: 'blue'
                    }
                },
                circle : false
            },
            edit: {
            featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
                remove: true

        }


        });
```

but still I am getting the default marker and please point me in the doc `http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-latlngutil` where should I see to know about the configuration and how to do it

Comment: See tutorial here:- http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign marker option icon property a marker icon.

1. Create your custom marker icon using Leaflet `L.Icon` class.

   ```
   var customMarker= L.Icon.extend({
       options: {
           shadowUrl: null,
           iconAnchor: new L.Point(12, 12),
           iconSize: new L.Point(24, 24),
           iconUrl: 'http://joshuafrazier.info/images/firefox.svg'
       }
   });
   ```
2. assign `customMarker` to marker icon property

   ```
   var  drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
     draw : {
       position : 'topleft',
       polygon : {
         shapeOptions: {
           color: 'red'
         }
       },
       marker: {
         icon: new customMarker() //Here assign your custom marker
       },
       polyline : false,
       rectangle : {
         shapeOptions: {
           color: 'blue'
         }
       },
       circle : false
     },
     edit: {
       featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
       remove: true
     }
   });
   ```